# Get a Sublayout's DataSource in validator implementation

Tags: c#, validation, sitecore, asp.net-3.5

I am using Sitecore 6.6 and I have a Sublayout item with a custom parameter template. The param template has the usual General section (Placeholder and Data Source fields) and a custom "Lock" section which has just a checkbox field. I added a custom field validator on the checkbox, which is to ensure that if the box is ticked - a DataSource is provided. In my validator implementation I inherited the StandardValidator class and I can check the checkbox's value with this

```
var currentItem = GetItem();
currentItem.Fields["Lock"].Value
```

as well as through this parameter

```
ControlValidationValue
```

However I can't find a way to access the data source field. All of the guides I found get it using the below code, but that applies to classes inheriting the Web.UI.UserControl class (rendering controller)

```
if(Parent is Sublayout)
    _dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(((Sublayout)Parent).DataSource);
```

I need to validate in the StandardValidator implementation in order to provide feedback in the Content Editor and to prevent the item saving if the validation fails. So how can I get to the DataSource field's value in the StandardValidator implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally. The custom validator class can inherit the StandardValidator class, but the Sitecore Validator Item calling the custom class must be an ItemValidator, not FieldValidator. Otherwise there is no way to access the data source field. The drawback of ItemValidator is that you need to add it to each item that uses the sublayout with the parameter template and then filter out the renderings/sublayouts that don't have the parameter template.

Use the below line to get all rendering references (from Sitecore Climber's answer)

```
var renderingRefs = GetItem().Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, false);
```

Then you need to filter out the irrelevant renderings - e.g. match them against a list of item GUIDs or templateIDs that use your param template. Once you have filtered out the irrelevant rendering(s), access the DataSource like this:

```
var dataSource = myRendering.Settings.DataSource;
```

Also, Sitecore just got back to me and basically confirmed what I said above. Below is their response

> The parameters of a rendering are not stored in a specific item in content tree, but in the __renderings field of the item that has this rendering.
>   So, in order to check the value of the DataSource parameter, you should create a validator for the content item and use the following API to get rendering and its datasource:

```
    foreach (var rendering in item.Visualization.GetRenderings(
        new DeviceItem(master.GetItem("{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}")), //get correct device item here
        false))
    {
        if(rendering.RenderingID == new ID("some rendering ID"))
            //do something with rendering.Settings.DataSource here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get datasources of an item, I didn't test in a standardValidator but I guess it will work

```
public static class ItemExtensions
{
    public static RenderingReference[] GetRenderingReferences(this Item i)
    {
        if (i == null)
        {
            return new RenderingReference[0];
        }
        return i.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, false);
    }

    public static List<Item> GetDataSourceItems(this Item i)
    {
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
        foreach (RenderingReference reference in i.GetRenderingReferences())
        {
            Item dataSourceItem = reference.GetDataSourceItem();
            if (dataSourceItem != null)
            {
                list.Add(dataSourceItem);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static Item GetDataSourceItem(this RenderingReference reference)
    {
        if (reference != null)
        {
            return GetDataSourceItem(reference.Settings.DataSource, reference.Database);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Item GetDataSourceItem(string id, Database db)
    {
        Guid itemId;
        return Guid.TryParse(id, out itemId)
                                ? db.GetItem(new ID(itemId))
                                : db.GetItem(id);
    }
}
```

In the validator class you will use :

```
foreach (Item dataSourceItem in GetItem().GetDataSourceItems())
{ 
  //your code
}
```

Comment: The line `i.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, false)` returns 0 rendering references.